# Reversing till underscore is found

Tags: c, string

I was writing a C program to reverse the portion of a string before the first underscore character is found '_'

**For Example:**
If the input is

```
black_black
```

The output must be

```
kcalb_black
```

Another input,

```
nounderscore
```

Must reverse the whole string

```
erocsrednuon
```

Another possibility of input,

```
_intact
```

Provides,

```
_intact
```

My code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char stringTillUnderscore[100], stringAfterUnderscore[100], inputString[100];
    int count = 0, counter = 0;
    fgets(inputString, 100, stdin);
    while(inputString[count] != '_') {
        stringTillUnderscore[count] = inputString[count];
        count++;
    }
    for(counter = strlen(stringTillUnderscore) - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
        printf("%c", stringTillUnderscore[counter]);
    }
    for(counter = strlen(stringTillUnderscore); counter < strlen(inputString); counter++) {
        printf("%c", inputString[counter]);
    }

}
```

Why doesn't my code work? It just returns garbage values.

Comment: You aren’t taking null terminators into account anywhere, `inputString[count] != '_'` doesn’t check for the end of the string, `stringTillUnderscore` isn’t null-terminated. You can do this in an easier way without copying, though, if you start with a function to reverse a string of a given length in place.

Comment: Show some sample outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missing null terminating the string

i.e.

```
 ....
 count++;
}
stringTillUnderscore[count] = 0;
```

Also

```
while(inputString[count] != '_') {
```

should be

```
while (inputString[count] && inputString[count] != '_') {
```

Just in case that the string does not have an underscore in it.

Comment: @jonathanLeffer - thanks for the edit. I was being lazy and if at work I would put in the comparison with `0`

Answer (score 1):

you just forgot to include the 
    **string.h**

there is no need to include 
    **stdlib.h**

also there is no need to declare the character array
    *stringAfterUnderscore[100]*

working code is,

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char stringTillUnderscore[100], inputString[100];
  int count = 0, counter = 0;
  fgets(inputString, 100, stdin);
  while(inputString[count] != '_')
    {
      stringTillUnderscore[count] = inputString[count];
      count++;
    }
  for(counter = strlen(stringTillUnderscore) - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
    {
      printf("%c", stringTillUnderscore[counter]);
    }
  for(counter = strlen(stringTillUnderscore); counter < strlen(inputString); counter++)
    {
      printf("%c", inputString[counter]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```